# Condense multiple rows into one single, for many instances

Tags: php, sql, pdo, left-join

I have a `table` called `Orders`, and another called `orderProducts`.

`orderProducts` contains a `CustomerID` field, `listCustomerOrders()` then looks for matching rows in the `DB`. The output returned would be as followed:

```
array() {
  [0]=>
  object(Basket)#3 (11) {
    ["ProductName"]=>
    string(17) "Green Pesto Bagel"
    ["completeDate"]=>
    string(19) "2015-02-25 11:00:00"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Basket)#4 (11) { 
    ["ProductName"]=>
    string(12) "Cheese Bagel"
    ["completeDate"]=>
    string(19) "2015-02-25 11:00:00"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Basket)#4 (11) { 
    ["ProductName"]=>
    string(12) "Salt Beef Bagel"
    ["completeDate"]=>
    string(19) "2015-02-25 11:00:00"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Basket)#4 (11) { 
    ["ProductName"]=>
    string(12) "Veggie Bagel"
    ["completeDate"]=>
    string(19) "2015-02-25 11:00:00"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(Basket)#4 (11) { 
    ["ProductName"]=>
    string(12) "Chicken Bagel"
    ["completeDate"]=>
    string(19) "2015-03-25 20:30:00"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(Basket)#4 (11) { 
    ["ProductName"]=>
    string(12) "Cheese Salad"
    ["completeDate"]=>
    string(19) "2015-03-25 20:30:00"
  }
}
```

And displayed as;

```
------1st order, date:02-25-15 11:00-------
Green Pesto Bagel
Cheese Bagel
Salt Beef Bagel
Veggie Bagel
------2nd order, date:03-25-15 11:00-------
Chicken Bagel
Cheese Salad
```

I would like to know how to approach outputting one result per `orderDate`, whilst iterating over each `row` for any additional products and adding them to the array.

Could I use some sort of counter to iterate through each block of code, and progress onto the next when a condition is met?

Here are the functions, cheers!

```
function myAccount(){

    require_once('classes/basket.php');

    // pull the customers order
    $CustomerID = $_SESSION['CustomerID'];
    $Limit = 20;

    $results = Basket::listCustomersOrders($CustomerID, $Limit);
    $orders['orders'] = $results['results'];

    include('templates/myAccount.php');
}

public static function listCustomersOrders($CustomerID, $Limit){


    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );
    $sql = "SELECT Orders.OrderID, Orders.payPalRef, Orders.SubTotal, Orders.completeDate, 
            OrderProducts.Quantity, OrderProducts.ProductName, OrderStatus.Status
            FROM Orders 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderProducts
            ON Orders.OrderID = OrderProducts.OrderID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN OrderStatus
            ON Orders.OrderStatusID = OrderStatus.OrderStatusID
            WHERE CustomerID = :CustomerID AND (Status = 'Cash on Delivery' or Status = 'PayPal') ORDER BY CompleteDate DESC LIMIT :Limit";

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->bindValue( ":CustomerID", $CustomerID, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->bindValue( ":Limit", $Limit, PDO::PARAM_INT );
    $st->execute();

    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
       $basket = new Basket( $row );
       $list[] = $basket;
    }

    //var_dump($list);


    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list ) );

}
```

Comment: Only read this superficially but sounds like a job for `group by`

Comment: Please explain desired output more fully. An example with 4-5 orders and 3 with the same date would be helpful.

Comment: Have updated my question as requested @PeterBowers. developerwjk, I have had a look at gro by and cant seem to see how it will help. Would you mind explaining? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$lastdate = null;
$ordercnt = 1;
foreach ($orders[´orders´] as $row) {
    if ($lastdate != $row[´completeDate´]) {
        echo '--Order #'.$ordercnt++.' Date '.$row[´completeDate´].'--<br />';
        $lastdate = $row[´completeDate´]
    }
    echo $row[´ProductName´].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: If this answers, please mark it as the answer. If not, please clarify the question.

Comment: hi Peter, with some slight modification this did the job. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peters inout I have created a script that does the job.

```
// Init the counters and vars
$lastdate = null;
$ordercnt = 1;
$output = "";

while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
    // if CompleteDate exists proceed
    if ($lastdate != $row['completeDate']) {

        if($lastdate != null){
          $output .="
                    <form action=\"reorder\" method=\"post\">
                          <button value=\"".$row['OrderID']."\" name=\"OrderID\" class=\"green-button\" style=\"width: 110px;float: right;margin-top: -40px;\">Order</button>
                    </form>
                </ul><hr>";
        }

        $output .= '<ul class="previousOrderList"><li>Order #'.$ordercnt++.', Date: '.$row['completeDate'].'-- Total '.$row['SubTotal'].'</li>';
        $output .= '<li>'.$row['Status'].' -- Total: '.$row['SubTotal'].'</li>';

        $lastdate = $row['completeDate'];

    }
    $output .='<li>'.$row['ProductName']." x ".$row['Quantity'].'</li>';
}
if ($output){$output .= "</ul>";}     // if there is results, add the end of line here

$conn = null;
return $output;
}
```